In an $n$-body system, do all bodies accelerate towards center of mass?
I've been building an $n$-body simulator as a way to learn a new game engine, and I've come across something that isn't necessarily a problem, but has intrigued me. Most other simulators I'm seeing will iteratively "assemble" the acceleration a body experiences due to gravity, such that:
$$\begin{align}
\vec{F_G}(A) &\equiv \text{Gravitational force on A exerted by all other bodies in the system} \\
&= \sum^n_{i=1}\ \lbrack{\ G \frac{m_A m_i}{\left|\vec{AB_i}\right|^2}}\ \cdot\ \frac{\vec{AB_i}}{\left|\vec{AB_i}\right|}\ \rbrack
\end{align}$$
I realize that I can't just roll this into a non-iterative solution (I'm not that smart), but I was curious if the result of this process will always point towards the center of mass:
$$\begin{align}
\vec{M_c} &\equiv \text{Center of mass of the $n$-body system} \\
&= \frac{\sum m_i \vec{B_i}}{\sum m_i}
\end{align}$$
I haven't quite been able to solve this out. Is this true?

There are special properties that hold for the centre of mass, but it is extremely notorious that the acceleration of bodies will not be directed to the centre of mass, and that causes the 3-body problem to have horrendous solutions. The issue, however, is what precisely are you actually trying to ask?

Correct, I was not aware of that. Could you point me towards some examples?

Consider the Sun-Earth-Moon system. The center of mass is approximately the center of the Sun. What is the acceleration of the Moon?

Towards the Earth lol, I see your point. I don't know why I thought this might be true.

@JonCuster that was my first thought as well, but actually the Moon is accelerated more towards the Sun ($3.8\times10^{-6}:\mathrm{\tfrac{m}{s^2}}$) than to Earth ($1.8\times10^{-6}:\mathrm{\tfrac{m}{s^2}}$).

...of course, the acceleration vector of the moon still does not point exactly at the Sun-Earth-Moon CM, but at least it never points away from it like one might think when considering that the Moon orbits the Earth.

Voting to reopen. "This question appears to be about engineering" ?? Really ???

I wasn't quite sure how to lay things out, but essentially $A$ is the spatial position of the body I'm calculating the force on and $i$ is (in each loop of the summation) the spatial position of other body that I'm calculating gravitational forces with. I haven't used $A_i$. $p_i$ is intended to be the position of $i$, I guess that was kinda inconsistent.

FWIW, I have some info (with diagrams) on the motion of the SSB (Solar System Barycenter) relative to the Sun here: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/28036/16685

If you are trying to optimize the calculations to not have $O(n^2)$ force calculation, there is an $O(n\log n)$ algorithm that is widely used (though there's still a faster method)

@KyleKanos thank you for this! I'm doing testing with only 3 bodies so far to make it simple, but I will absolutely use these when I'm scaling things up.

Consider a simple 3-body system, star-planet-moon. Its center of mass will generally be inside the body of the star or at least very close, because the star is by far the heaviest. So if your conjecture was true, the planet and moon should always accelerate towards the star. But at New Moon, i.e. when the moon is between the star and the planet, it will be attracted more strongly towards the planet (and thus away from the CM), because the planet is much closer.
This does not hold for all moons (notably, not for the Moon), but at least for close-orbiting ones around large and distant planets it does. E.g. Ganymede experiences an acceleration of $6.6\times10^{-5}\:\mathrm{\tfrac{m}{s^2}}$ towards Jupiter, but the Jupiter system only experiences an acceleration of $1.4\times10^{-7}\:\mathrm{\tfrac{m}{s^2}}$ towards the Sun. It also holds for satellites orbiting the Earth more closely than the Moon. On a much larger scale, it holds for the solar system in which the planets are more attracted to the Sun than they are to the center of the Milky Way, etc. etc..
